# 'In a way' or 'in the way'?

Tags: grammar, articles, formal-language

Could you please help with the following:

Are both options correct? If so, what is the difference between those? Otherwise, why one option is incorrect?

> Most schools are still organised **in a way** that puts a lot
> of psychological pressure on the pupils.

> Most schools are still organised **in the way** that puts a lot
> of psychological pressure on the pupils.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The option "in the way" suggests that there is only one standard, well known way of applying pressure.

The option "in a way" suggests that there could be multiple ways in which the pressure could be applied.